# Finite element analysis software for acoustic and electrostatic

Tags: finite-element, simulation

I need to do a simulation for my thesis project involving some piezoelectric nanoparticles in a fluid beamed with ultrasounds. I'm looking for a software for such simulation and for now it seems me only COMSOL Multiphysics has acoustic and electrostatic modules for finite element analysis. Do you recommend it? Can you suggests some others for getting a better decision? Are this software scriptable in a way I can randomize the nanoparticles location in the mesh for different simulations?

Comment: Do your project involves fluid-structure interaction?

Comment: Yes, i have to model an interface of a solid and a liquid, the particles being in the liquid phase.

Comment: That might be something useful to add to your question. That being said, the simulation seems a little bit complex.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have never used these modules you mentioned, I do believe Comsol is an appropriate choice. My experience with the software was very positive a couple of years ago, mainly because of its support team.

Unfortunately I cannot compare it to other alternatives because I have never used another commercial multiphysics FE software.

You can parametrize the locations of the particles within Comsol, but I believe that in order to control them externally with an script you need an additional module. I'd suggest trying to contact them.